# How to calculate cumulative values within a column

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the cumulative time among several grades.

Here's how my original `df` looks like:

```
df = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                group = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
                grade = c(0,1,2,3,0,1,3,4),
                time = c(10,7,4,1,20,17,14,11))
```

Here's what I'm expecting as the result `df1`:

```
df1 = df %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = "grade",
    names_prefix = "grade_",
    values_from = "time") %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  
  mutate(grade_1 = grade_1 + grade_2 + grade_3 + grade_4,
         grade_2 = grade_2 + grade_3 + grade_4,
         grade_3 = grade_3 + grade_4) %>%
  
  pivot_longer(
    cols = 3:7,
    names_to = "grade",
    names_prefix = "grade_",
    values_to = "time")
```

My method works, but I want it to be more flexible. When I have more grades in the df, I don't need to manually add grade_x = grade_1 + grade_2 + grade_3 ...

Thank you!

Comment: Can u show final output. Your code for output returns 10 records while input is 8 records. Also for cumulating so much pivots wide and long may not be required. We can try something with group_by and summarise I think, once you show me desired output table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to rearrange the `grade` column, then do `cumsum` so that it is in reverse. However, we exclude the last row, where `grade == 0`.  Then, we can re-arrange back in the desired order and ungroup.

```
library(tidyverse)

results <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(id, desc(grade)) %>%
  mutate(time = ifelse(row_number()!=n(), cumsum(time), time)) %>%
  arrange(id, grade) %>%
  ungroup
```

**Output**

```
     id group grade  time
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     0    10
2     1     0     1    12
3     1     0     2     5
4     1     0     3     1
5     2     1     0    20
6     2     1     1    42
7     2     1     3    25
8     2     1     4    11
```

If you need each group to have the same number of rows as in your desired output, then you can use `complete`:

```
df %>%
  tidyr::complete(id, grade) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  fill(group, .direction ="downup") %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
  arrange(id, desc(grade)) %>%
  mutate(time = ifelse(row_number()!=n(), cumsum(time), time)) %>%
  arrange(id, grade) %>%
  ungroup
```

*Output*

```
      id grade group  time
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     0     0    10
 2     1     1     0    12
 3     1     2     0     5
 4     1     3     0     1
 5     1     4     0     0
 6     2     0     1    20
 7     2     1     1    42
 8     2     2     1    25
 9     2     3     1    25
10     2     4     1    11
```

Or if you want to pivot back and forth then you could do something like this:

```
output <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = "grade",
    names_prefix = "grade_",
    values_from = "time") %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  select(id, group, grade_0, last_col():grade_1)

results2 <- output %>% 
  select(-c(id, group, grade_0)) %>% 
  rowwise()%>% 
  do(data.frame(t(cumsum(unlist(.))))) %>% 
  bind_cols(select(output, id, group, grade_0), .) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = 3:7,
    names_to = "grade",
    names_prefix = "grade_",
    values_to = "time")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution works! One question, why we need ```grp2``` here?

Comment: @xshbj Since nothing needed to be calculated for the first row in each group (or `grade_0` in your wide pivot), I just pulled it out by itself so that it would remain unchanged.

Comment: @xshbj Actually, I found a better way to do it by just using `ifelse` rather than adding more groups, etc. This change cuts out a few lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

## 1st Try:

for cumulative sums across a variable, we can group_by and use cumsum() :
No need to specify grades, etc. You can do more aggregations if needed.

```
df%>%
  group_by(grade)%>%
  mutate(Cum_Time = cumsum(time))%>%arrange(grade)

     id group grade  time Cum_Time
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1     0     0    10       10
2     2     1     0    20       30
3     1     0     1     7        7
4     2     1     1    17       24
5     1     0     2     4        4
6     1     0     3     1        1
7     2     1     3    14       15
8     2     1     4    11       11
```